# What complexity classes does this expression belong to?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

[image]

Are Oh, Omega and Theta all (n ^ 3)?

I know Omega should be at least n ^ 3 so it is right.

Oh is the upper limit and the greatest term is n ^ 3.

But Theta should be more explicit so I am not sure.

And can we say that the following complexities are right for this expression?
Omega(1), Oh(n ^ 4) because the expression complexity is higher than 1 and less than n ^ 4.

Comment: Did my answer help answer your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right.

Big-ϴ is not "more explicit" than big-O or big-Omega, it just describes equivalence between complexity classes. This function is *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*, *Ω(n<sup>3</sup>)* and *ϴ(n<sup>3</sup>)*, as you say. But it is also *O(n<sup>100</sup>)*, or *Ω(n)*.

You confirm this yourself, when you say that your function is in *Ω(1)* and in *O(n<sup>4</sup>)*. So yes, it seems you understand the definitions.